# Control videoplayer with footpedal

Tags: .net, windows, google-chrome-extension, media-player, hid

I made a footpedal (with an Arduino) that connects as a HID over USB to my PC. Goal is to pause/play the currently playing video whilest not being the active window. Use case: watch a tutoral while making notes / entering code in a different window and use my food to control the video. Extra nice bonus would be a second pedal to jump back 10 seconds.

Anyhow, I tried using HID_USAGE_CONSUMER_PLAY_PAUSE just like the media buttons on a keyboard. But this proved to be a poor solution. It is just not reliable in starting the video again. I experience the same behaviour with the mediakey on my keyboard. Also there are no HID defines for jumping back 10 seconds or so.

My conclusion is that I need a totally different approach. My questions to you is: which approach and why?

I was thinking about making a .net system tray application that manually lets me choose which application to control (e.g. a drop down, or point and click the App) and have this .net app 'translate' special HID keys (which ones to be used?) to an action to control the selected App. Couple of problems to address here:

- Which special HID keys can I use to identify it comming from my pedals. I also saw a project that uses MIDI signals for controlling OBS via a obs-plugin.
- How to control youtube playing in a browser from a different App? Do I need to make a plugin for each of my browsers?
- Same question for VLC & MS-Mediaplayer.

So many uncertainties here.....

What would you do to achieve the same goal (pause/play active video, not being the active window)? Bonus for a 'rewinding 10 seconds' solution.